# Elasticsearch receives anonymous shutdown request

Tags: ubuntu, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2

I have a 1-master, 7-slave elasticsearch setup on amazon ec2. Recently the ec2 instance on which the master node(version 1.5.2) was hosted failed and all applications were shutdown. It has since been restarted and its stable, but this failure has somehow affected the master node. Each time elasticsearch is started on the master node, it receives an anonymous shutdown request and proceeds to shutdown. There is no error message of any sort, just the log statement indicating that a shutdown request was received. I have ensured that none of the clients or browsers are connected to the cluster when the master is restarted, but I always end up with the same issue. The related log snippet is below. Any help debugging this will be appreciated

```
2015-06-15 14:10:22,874][DEBUG][gateway.local            ] [NoDataMasterNode] [sourcedocument2015h2][0]: not allocating, number_of_allocated_shards_found [0], required_number [1]
[2015-06-15 14:10:22,874][DEBUG][gateway.local            ] [NoDataMasterNode] [sourcedocument2015h1][6]: not allocating, number_of_allocated_shards_found [0], required_number [1]
[2015-06-15 14:10:22,874][DEBUG][cluster.service          ] [NoDataMasterNode] processing [routing-table-updater]: no change in cluster_state
[2015-06-15 14:10:43,862][INFO ][action.admin.cluster.node.shutdown] [NoDataMasterNode] [cluster_shutdown]: requested, shutting down in [1s]
[2015-06-15 14:10:44,864][INFO ][action.admin.cluster.node.shutdown] [NoDataMasterNode] [cluster_shutdown]: done shutting down all nodes except master, proceeding to master
[2015-06-15 14:10:44,867][INFO ][action.admin.cluster.node.shutdown] [NoDataMasterNode] shutting down in [200ms]
[2015-06-15 14:10:45,068][INFO ][action.admin.cluster.node.shutdown] [NoDataMasterNode] initiating requested shutdown...
[2015-06-15 14:10:45,068][INFO ][node                     ] [NoDataMasterNode] stopping ...
[2015-06-15 14:10:45,082][INFO ][node                     ] [NoDataMasterNode] stopped
[2015-06-15 14:10:45,082][INFO ][node                     ] [NoDataMasterNode] closing ...
[2015-06-15 14:10:45,108][INFO ][node                     ] [NoDataMasterNode] closed
```

Comment: Are you sure port 9200 is not open to the world? Or somehow someone is interfering with your cluster?

Comment: That was my first guess, I checked and I let one of our system admins also double check, they run a monitor on that port, there was nothing. I also shut down all other elasticsearch instances, just in case

Comment: Try [disabling the shutdown](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-nodes-shutdown.html#_disable_shutdown) command.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the shutdown command would be more of a hack than a good solution as it just blocks the problem and also will block the automated monitoring tool in future if the system needs to be shutdown safely. I couldn't determine the cause of the problem but we were able to rule out elasticsearch as the source. It seems the shutdown was coming from a possibly corrupted instance. My alternative, zipped up the current state of elasticsearch and copied it over to a new instance. It is working perfectly on the new ec2 instance. Since that worked for me, I will mark this as answered. I would like to explore the cause further but I really do not have the cycles to spend on figuring out what corrupted the system.